# Colored Output from Bash Script

Tags: bash, shell-script, grep

I'm running `grep` inside a bash script. If I run the `grep` command directly, I see colored output of the file name and search string:

```
grep -i username /tmp/sess_*
```

If I put that command in a bash script, it works, but the colors are lost. How can I preserve the colored output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could add `--color=always` to your grep.

Relevant section from my local manpage:

> ```
>   --color[=WHEN], --colour[=WHEN]
>           Surround  the  matched  (non-empty)  strings,  matching   lines,
>           context  lines,  file  names,  line  numbers,  byte offsets, and
>           separators (for fields and groups of context lines) with  escape
>           sequences  to display them in color on the terminal.  The colors
>           are  defined  by  the  environment  variable  GREP_COLORS.   The
>           deprecated  environment  variable GREP_COLOR is still supported,
>           but its setting does not have priority.  WHEN is never,  always,
>           or auto.
> ```

As [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9550885/grep-loses-coloring-when-run-from-bash-script) on SO suggests, probably you have an alias for `grep` that maps it to `grep --color=auto` in your `.bashrc` and that isn't read by the script, and so isn't applied within the script.

Comment: Awesome! This worked perfectly.